# How to add space before or after if there is no space for a particular word in python without regex

Tags: python

I have a string like below.

```
txt1 = "Krish is a school boy and Mahesh is anotherschool boy, Gang is good schoolboy"
```

Currently I am replacing **school** word with spaces as below

```
txt1.lower().replace("school"," school ")
```

But, due to above replace, it is adding another space, although there is a space, which means I am getting output as below. Is there a way if there is no space then only add space.

```
'krish is a  school  boy and mahesh is another school  boy, gang is good  school boy'
```

I am expecting output like below: Any best way to handle this case, without regex.

```
'Krish is a school boy and Mahesh is another school boy, Gang is good school boy'
```

Note: please ignore case sensitivity

Comment: If you insist on not using regex theny ou can just replace your double spaces at the end so something like `txt1.lower().replace("school"," school ").replace("  ", " ")`

Answer (score 2):

#### Without regex

I would add a replacement for 2 spaces into one `.replace("  ", " ")` and a `strip()` in case you  had the word as first of last word

```
txt1 = "Krish is a school boy and Mahesh is anotherschool boy, Gang is good schoolboy"

txt1 = txt1.lower().replace("school", " school ").replace("  ", " ").strip()
```

#### With regex

```
import re

txt1 = "Krish is a school boy and Mahesh is anotherschool boy, Gang is good schoolboy"

txt1 = re.sub(r"school(\S)", r"school \1", txt1)
txt1 = re.sub(r"(\S)school", r"\1 school", txt1)
```

Comment: This won't work properly if the target is at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: @ekhumoro then add `.strip()`

Comment: @Nullman I was pointing out the bug, not asking how to fix it.